# Problems while calculating second grade complex numbers results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing an exercise using MySQL to calculate the second grade function results. I'm triying to calculate the complex results, but when I want to insert them into the table, I get this output:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    | x1   | x2   |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|   78 |   56 |   45 | p    | p    |
|   59 |   59 |   20 | p    | p    |
|   21 |   46 |   68 | p    | p    |
|    3 |   11 |   45 | p    | p    |
|   93 |   33 |   83 | p    | p    |
|   19 |   46 |   75 | p    | p    |
   .       .      .     .      .
   .       .      .     .      .
   .       .      .     .      .
|    4 |   18 |   78 | -    | -    |
|   38 |   56 |   67 | -    | -    |
|   68 |   38 |   86 | -    | -    |
|   16 |   22 |   62 | -    | -    |
|   72 |   51 |   39 | -    | -    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

This is the table:

```
create table RES_COMPLEJOS (
    a float references INCOGNITAS,
    b float references INCOGNITAS,
    c float references INCOGNITAS,
    x1 char,
    x2 char
);
```

And the procedure:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists calcularComplejo;
create procedure calcularComplejo (a int, b int, c int)
begin
    declare real float;
    declare imaginary float;
    declare discriminante float default -(b*b - 4*a*c);
    declare x1 char;
    declare x2 char;
    set real = -b / 2*a;
    set imaginary = sqrt(discriminante) / 2*a;
    set x1 = concat(real,'+',imaginary,'*i');
    set x2 = concat(real,'-',imagginary,'*i');
    insert into res_complejos values (a, b, c, x1, x2);
end; $$
```

I don't know where's the problem. This is one of my first projects and any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: You need to specify the size of the `char` type, like `char(10)`. If you leave out the size, it defaults to `char(1)` and can only hold a single character.

Comment: As @Barmar says you need to specify the size of it. And also, you probably want to use `VARCHAR(100)` instead of `CHAR` since you don't need the text to be padded with blanks.

Comment: I have specified x1 and x2 as VARCHAR(100) and now I get this output: https://photos.app.goo.gl/gLu1D14q69KT1qFu6